# How can I have multiple pages on a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first time using React, so I'm not certain how to approach this.

I am creating a React app for a chatbot, where I want the end screen to transition to a feedback rating similar to the one here (https://medium.com/@mailjontay/make-a-dynamic-emoticon-satisfaction-rating-with-react-4c7cb1b92fb).

I have one .js file that contains my chatbot and one .js file that contains my star rating. At the end of my chatbot .js file, I call `export default chatbot;`, which seems to render my chatbot.

How can I then call my star rating JS file?

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I didn't understand what are you trying to ask but if you want navigation in your app you can use react-router